# Implementing a movable QGraphicsObject subclass

Tags: qt, draggable, qgraphicsitem

I'm trying to make a QGraphicObject that represents a Rectangle with rounded corners that can me moved using the mouse.

The item seems to be drawn correctly, And after searching in the docs I found that i had to set the flag `QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable`  which made the item move in the right direction but it always moves faster than the mouse, so what am I doing wrong ?

Here is the .h file :

```
class GraphicRoundedRectObject : public GraphicObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit GraphicRoundedRectObject(
            qreal x ,
            qreal y ,
            qreal width ,
            qreal height ,
            qreal radius=0,
            QGraphicsItem *parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~GraphicRoundedRectObject();


    qreal radius() const;
    void setRadius(qreal radius);
    qreal height() const ;
    void setHeight(qreal height) ;
    qreal width() const ;
    void setWidth(qreal width) ;

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *, QWidget *) override;
    QRectF boundingRect() const override;

private:
    qreal m_radius;
    qreal m_width;
    qreal m_height;
};
```

And the .cpp :

```
#include "graphicroundedrectobject.h"
#include <QPainter>

GraphicRoundedRectObject::GraphicRoundedRectObject(
        qreal x ,
        qreal y ,
        qreal width ,
        qreal height ,
        qreal radius,
        QGraphicsItem *parent
        )
    : GraphicObject(parent)
    , m_radius(radius)
    , m_width(width)
    , m_height(height)
{
    setX(x);
    setY(y);
    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
}

GraphicRoundedRectObject::~GraphicRoundedRectObject() {
}

void GraphicRoundedRectObject::paint
(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *, QWidget*) {
    painter->drawRoundedRect(x(), y(),m_width, m_height, m_radius, m_radius );
}

QRectF GraphicRoundedRectObject::boundingRect() const {
    return QRectF(x(), y(), m_width, m_height);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are drawing the rectangle in parent coordinates rather than the object's coordinates.

It should be:

```
void GraphicRoundedRectObject::paint(QPainter *painter,
                                     const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *, QWidget*) {
    painter->drawRoundedRect(0.0, 0.0,m_width, m_height, m_radius, m_radius );
}

QRectF GraphicRoundedRectObject::boundingRect() const {
    return QRectF(0.0, 0.0, m_width, m_height);
}
```